# In my LinkedIn Oauth2.0.php access token's fetch function not responding any user content?

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

HI We are using LinkedIn API call at our website to get our website visitor details to logged in their profile through Linkedin.

The functionality was working fine but suddenly its stop working I checked in it.

We are getting Access Token Response in call but later on its fetching function is not working means not getting any values.I added some debug to check response and field value code and debug screenshot is attached

I tried to test made scope fields similar showing in app

```
define('SCOPE',        'r_basicprofile r_emailaddress'  ---> 
define('SCOPE',        'r_liteprofile r_emailaddress'
```

and update call code to latest method

```
https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization ->> https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization

https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken?  ->>
https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken
```

But still nothing change than I redo changs in code and this is the code

```
<?php
$config = include(dirname(__FILE__).'/config.php');
// Change these
define('API_KEY',      'XXXXXXXXX');
define('API_SECRET',   'XXXXXXXXX');
//define('REDIRECT_URI', ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on")?'https':'http').'://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
define('REDIRECT_URI', ('https://example.com/linkedin/OAuth2.php'));
define('SCOPE',        'r_basicprofile r_emailaddress'                        );

// You'll probably use a database
    session_name('linkedin');
    session_start();


// OAuth 2 Control Flow
if (isset($_GET['error'])) {
    // LinkedIn returned an error
    print $_GET['error'] . ': ' . $_GET['error_description'];
    exit;
} elseif (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    // User authorized your application

        getAccessToken();

} else { 
    if ((empty($_SESSION['expires_at'])) || (time() > $_SESSION['expires_at'])) {
        // Token has expired, clear the state
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = '';

    }
    if (empty($_SESSION['access_token']) || $_SESSION['access_token'] == '') {
        // Start authorization process
        getAuthorizationCode();
    }
}

echo "Fetching" . "<br>";
// Congratulations! You have a valid token. Now fetch your profile 
$user = fetch('GET', '/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,headline,email-address,picture-urls::(original),public-profile-url,picture-url,location,industry,site-standard-profile-request,interests,positions,summary,main-address,phone-numbers,skills:(skill))');

$userData = array('linkedin_id'=>'','first-name'=>'','last-name'=>'','picture-url'=>'','email-address'=>'','public_url'=>'','summary'=>'','twitter-account'=>'','headline'=>'','companyname'=>'','designation'=>'');


          foreach($user as $key=>$value)
          {


            if($key=='id')
                $userData['linkedin_id'] = $value;
            if($key=='firstName')
                $userData['first-name'] = $value;
            if($key=='lastName')
                $userData['last-name'] = $value;
            if($key=='pictureUrls')
            {
                $userData['picture-url'] = $value->values[0];
            }
            if($key=='pictureUrl' && $userData['picture-url']=='')
            {
                $userData['picture-url'] = $value;
            }

            if($key=='emailAddress')
                $userData['email-address'] = $value;    
            if($key=='publicProfileUrl'){
                $userData['public_url'] = $value;




                          } 
            if($key=='summary')
                $userData['summary'] = $value;  

            if($key=='twitter-accounts')
            {
                foreach($value as $key=>$val)
                 {
                    if($key=='twitter-account')
                    {
                        $valueTwit = json_encode($val); 
                        $valueTwit = json_decode($valueTwit,true);
                        $userData['twitter-account'] = $userData['twitter-account'].",".$valueTwit['provider-account-name'];
                    }
                 }
                 $userData['twitter-account'] = substr($userData['twitter-account'],1,strlen($userData['twitter-account']));
            }



            if($key=='headline')
                $userData['headline'] = $value;

                        if($key=='positions')
                               {

                                foreach($value as $key1=>$val)
                {

                     if($key1=='values')
                                {

                $company_array = $val[0];
                                 foreach($company_array as $key2=>$val1)
                 {
                                   if($key2=='company')
                                    {
                    foreach($val1 as $key3=>$val3)
                    {
                            if($key3=='name')
                                         {
                            $userData['companyname'] = $val3;
                            }
                    }
                                    }



                                 }
                                }
                                }
                               }

                        if($key=='positions')
                               {

                                foreach($value as $keys1=>$vals)
                {

                     if($keys1=='values')
                                {

                $company_array1 = $vals[0];
                                 foreach($company_array1 as $keys2=>$vals1)
                 {

                                   if($keys2=='title')
                                    {
                                        $userData['designation'] = $vals1;
                                    }


                                 }
                                }
                                }
                               }






          }

          $userRequiredDetails = "";
                   $random = rand();
          $userRequiredDetails.="?oid=".$userData['linkedin_id']."&email=".$userData['email-address']."&random=".$random;     

          $linkedinMenter_array =array('oid'=> $userData['linkedin_id']."<br/>",'first_name'=>$userData['first-name']."<br/>",'last_name'=>$userData['last-name']."<br/>",'image'=>$userData['picture-url']."<br/>",'email'=>$userData['email-address']."<br/>",'public_url'=>$userData['public_url']."<br/>",'summary'=>$userData['summary']."<br/>",'twitter-account'=>$userData['twitter-account']."<br/>",'headline'=>$userData['headline']."<br/>", 'companyname'=>$userData['companyname']."<br/>", 'designation'=>$userData['designation']."<br/>",'questionId'=>$questionId, 'questionURL'=>$questionURL, 'projectId'=>$projectId, 'directoryConsultationId'=>$directoryConsultationId, 'feedbackId' => $feedbackId, 'mentorshipId' => $mentorshipId, 'plan_id' => $plan_id, 'planUserId' => $planUserId, 'sresult' => $sresult, 'projectUserId' => $projectUserId);
           echo "Request token retrieval failed:<br /><br />RESPONSE:<br /><br /><pre>" . print_r($linkedinMenter_array, TRUE) . "</pre><br /><br />LINKEDIN OBJ:<br /><br /><pre>" . print_r($OBJ_linkedin, TRUE) . "</pre>";
           exit;          
          /* for data write in file */
          $file = "../".$userData['linkedin_id'].".txt";
          file_put_contents($file, $linkedinMenter_array);        
                 echo $file;
                 exit;
          //header("location:https://example.com/users/signuplinkedin".$userRequiredDetails);


function getAuthorizationCode() {
    $params = array('response_type' => 'code',
                    'client_id' => API_KEY,
                    'scope' => SCOPE,
                    'state' => uniqid('', true), // unique long string
                    'redirect_uri' => REDIRECT_URI,
              );

    // Authentication request
    $url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?' . http_build_query($params);

    // Needed to identify request when it returns to us
    $_SESSION['state'] = $params['state'];

echo print_r($_SESSION, TRUE) . "\n<br>";
echo print_r($params, TRUE) . "\n<br>";

echo "Pankaj getAuthorizationCode";

    // Redirect user to authenticate
    header("Location: $url");
    exit;
}

function getAccessToken() {
    $params = array('grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
                    'client_id' => API_KEY,
                    'client_secret' => API_SECRET,
                    'code' => $_GET['code'],
                    'redirect_uri' => REDIRECT_URI,
              );

    // Access Token request
    $url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken?' . http_build_query($params);

    // Tell streams to make a POST request
    $context = stream_context_create(
                    array('http' => 
                        array('method' => 'POST',
                        )
                    )
                );

    // Retrieve access token information
    $response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

    // Native PHP object, please
    $token = json_decode($response);
 echo print_r($token, TRUE) . "\n<br>";
    // Store access token and expiration time
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $token->access_token; // guard this! 
    $_SESSION['expires_in']   = $token->expires_in; // relative time (in seconds)
    $_SESSION['expires_at']   = time() + $_SESSION['expires_in']; // absolute time

echo "Pankaj getAccessToken"  . "\n<br>";
    return true;
}

function fetch($method, $resource, $body = '') {
    $params = array('oauth2_access_token' => $_SESSION['access_token'],
                    'format' => 'json',
              );

    // Need to use HTTPS
    $url = 'https://api.linkedin.com' . $resource . '?' . http_build_query($params);
    // Tell streams to make a (GET, POST, PUT, or DELETE) request
    $context = stream_context_create(
                    array('http' => 
                        array('method' => $method,
                        )
                    )
                );

    // Hocus Pocus
    $response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
   //echo($response);
    // Native PHP object, please
    return json_decode($response);
}
```

Getting this as a response in debug mode

```
stdClass Object ( [access_token] => AQX7maxbOfOpday8AEmpHyagkSKQcS26YYwMsocDx0FeIGPVwopJstJ27bqlSYrP754vT_DY6n1HoSr0kniJYY-RvhqvnX9ab4sczmzOYiqKo5p1ISVydiZJ_SiN-on9Hw12zD3tiktfvIPex6iHIi0dVhZ5-8CWWvdTX2Sj_d7YAusr9dJAmWQiNE3Aowe-i5cLlZSE-sOpzudCm3dns-ou2A4hg_NMLe5RAJcCQ2TlrGOiA29-1rZsN1_SJw5r4ZjLsx0HY8yUKmxmB1CnfOfg31y1RwlsDAaG679ILyGFvEqhdVJhcRrNzsHaI3JrDc1MJZTGAkBDCJt6WK9FexvqYHOLpw [expires_in] => 5184000 ) 
Pankaj getAccessToken 
Fetching
Request token retrieval failed:

RESPONSE:

Array
(
    [oid] => 

    [first_name] => 

    [last_name] => 

    [image] => 

    [email] => 

    [public_url] => 

    [summary] => 

    [twitter-account] => 

    [headline] => 

    [companyname] => 

    [designation] => 

    [questionId] => 
    [questionURL] => 
    [projectId] => 
    [directoryConsultationId] => 
    [feedbackId] => 
    [mentorshipId] => 
    [plan_id] => 
    [planUserId] => 
    [sresult] => 
    [projectUserId] => 
)


LINKEDIN OBJ:
```

Comment: you should remove your access token from this post

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to receive access token

```
 $params = array('grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
            'client_id' => $this->api_key,
            'client_secret' => $this->api_secret,
            'code' => $_GET['code'],
            'redirect_uri' => base_url().$this->redirect,
        );
        // Access Token request
        $url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken?' . http_build_query($params);
        $data_len = strlen(http_build_query($params));
        // Tell streams to make a POST request
        $context = stream_context_create(
                array('http' =>
                    array('method' => 'POST','header'=> 'Content-Length: 0'
                    )
                )
        );

        // Retrieve access token information
        $response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
        $token = json_decode($response);
        return $token->access_token;
```

Comment: HI @augustine thanks for reply but nothing has changed I am still facing same issue token not converting in data we are getting token but nothing happened after that.You used this way($this->api_secret) of key values to call but as in my starting post I mentioned we are defined these key pairs as value name so I used API_SECRET that doesn't effect. But main goal to get content is not solved.

Comment: Once you received the access token use this EP (https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id,firstName,lastName,profilePicture(displayImage~:playableStreams))) to get the  profile details

Answer (score 0):

LinkedIn's v1 APIs have been deprecated, and you should be requesting the profile by sending a GET request to https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me.

Additionally, some users may have opted-out of sharing their data with 3rd party applications via LinkedIn APIs.